# Finding Midpoint ADT

Tags: c

A point represents a coordinate in an x-y plane. It is supported by the following functions:

```
Point * make_point(double x, double y)
double x_of(Point *p)
double y_of(Point *p)
void print_point(Point *p)
```

A function `Point * mid_point` that accepts two points as arguments and returns a point that is the mid-point of these two input coordinates.

when trying to run on online simulator for `mid_point(make_point(1.0, 1.0), make_point(3.0, 3.0))`it shows wrong

```
Point * mid_point(Point *x, Point *y) {

    int mid = make_point((x_of(x)+x_of(x))/2,(y_of(y)+y_of(y))/2);

    print_point(mid);

}
```

Comment: Well, what *is* wrong with the code? Learning to analyze your problems is the first step in getting them fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You have one extra bracket in the line:

```
return make_point( |(| (x_of (x) + x_of(x) ) / 2,  (y_of(y) + y_of(y) ) / 2);
    //Extra bracket ^  ^open               ^close  ^open              ^close
```

Also I'm pretty sure you meant to say:

```
return make_point((x_of (x) + x_of(|y|) ) / 2,  (y_of(|x|) + y_of(y) ) / 2);
                                   ^^^                ^^^
```

Also I would return a Point copy from make_point(double x, double y) instead of Point* pointer, otherwise you'll have to return a static variable or a global.

I think this is simpler:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct Point
{
    double x, y;

}Point;

Point getMidPointOf(Point p1, Point p2)
{
    Point newP = { (p1.x + p2.x) / 2.0, (p1.y + p2.y) / 2.0 };
    return newP;
}

int main()
{
    Point p1 = { 5.0, 15.0 };
    Point p2 = { 15.0, 30.0 };
    Point p3 = getMidPointOf(p1, p2);
    printf("Point value = (%f, %f)", p3.x, p3.y);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Point * mid_point(Point *a, Point *b) {

    Point * m;

    m = make_point((x_of (a) + x_of(b) ) / 2,  (y_of(a) + y_of(b) ) / 2);

    print_point(m);

    return m;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.